# Como agrupar y aplicar doble xsl:for-each en XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Amigos llevo días tratando de solucionar mi problema, por favor alguien podría ayudarme.
Estuve revisando documentación de como usar XPATH, XSLT, pero no he llegado a mucho.

trate de resolver de muchas maneras mi problemas pero me he quedado atascado, y debo configurar esto en una integración y ya me quede sin tiempo, la integración soporte xml v1.0.

Este es mi XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="tienda.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<Tiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>CT15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>ABAND-0000147</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>10</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>CX15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>ABAND-0000147</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>5</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>CT15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>13-AY0002LA</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>20</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>CT15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>IN4303116</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>15</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>ES15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>EFE-TEST-21062022</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>45</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>CT15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>EFE-TEST</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>20</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>CT15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>EFE-TEST</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>20</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>CT15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>EFE-TEST</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>20</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
    <NodoTiendas>
        <tienda_code>CX15</tienda_code>
        <item_code>EFE-TEST</item_code>
        <cantidad_disponible>5</cantidad_disponible>
    </NodoTiendas>
</Tiendas>
```

Necesito generar esta salida.

```
  <Tiendas>
  <NodoTiendas>
    <ItemCode>ABAND-0000147</ItemCode>
    <Stores>
        <tiendaNombre>CT15</tiendaNombre>
        <cantidad>10</cantidad>
    </Stores>
    <Stores>
        <tiendaNombre>CX15</tiendaNombre>
        <cantidad>5</cantidad>
    </Stores>
  </NodoTiendas>
  <NodoTiendas>
    <ItemCode>13-AY0002LA</ItemCode>
    <Stores>
        <tiendaNombre>CT15</tiendaNombre>
        <cantidad>20</cantidad>
    </Stores>
  </NodoTiendas>
  <NodoTiendas>
    <ItemCode>IN4303116</ItemCode>
    <Stores>
        <tiendaNombre>CT15</tiendaNombre>
        <cantidad>15</cantidad>
    </Stores>
  </NodoTiendas>
  <NodoTiendas>
    <ItemCode>EFE-TEST-21062022</ItemCode>
    <Stores>
        <tiendaNombre>CT15</tiendaNombre>
        <cantidad>45</cantidad>
    </Stores>
  </NodoTiendas>
  <NodoTiendas>
    <ItemCode>EFE-TEST</ItemCode>
    <Stores>
        <tiendaNombre>CT15</tiendaNombre>
        <cantidad>20</cantidad>
    </Stores>
    <Stores>
        <tiendaNombre>CX15</tiendaNombre>
        <cantidad>5</cantidad>
    </Stores>
  </NodoTiendas>
</Tiendas>
```

Estuve tratando de aplicar este código, pero no obtengo lo que quiero, es mas la segunda clave ni la reconoce.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="td" match="NodoTiendas" use="item_code" /> 
<xsl:key name="nd" match="NodoTiendas" use="concat(generate-id(..),item_code,tienda_code)" /> 

<xsl:template match="/Tiendas">
    <Tiendas>
        <xsl:for-each select="NodoTiendas[generate-id() = generate-id(key('td',item_code))]">
            <xsl:variable name="vTiendaCode" select="tienda_code"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vItemCode" select="item_code"/>
            <NodoTiendas>
                <ItemCode><xsl:value-of select="$vItemCode" /></ItemCode>

                <xsl:for-each select="NodoTiendas[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nd',concat(generate-id(..),item_code,tienda_code)))]">
                    <xsl:if test="$vTiendaCode = tienda_code and $vItemCode = item_code">
                        <Stores>
                            <tiendaNombre>
                                <xsl:value-of select="tienda_code" />
                            </tiendaNombre>
                            <cantidad>
                                <xsl:value-of select="cantidad_disponible" />
                            </cantidad>
                        </Stores>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </NodoTiendas>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Tiendas>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero que lo siguiente ayude:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:key name="agrupar-por-item" match="NodoTiendas" use="item_code"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/processing-instruction()"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NodoTiendas[generate-id() = generate-id(key('agrupar-por-item', item_code)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <ItemCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="item_code"/>
      </ItemCode>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('agrupar-por-item', item_code)" mode="store"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="NodoTiendas[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('agrupar-por-item', item_code)[1]))]"/>

  <xsl:template match="NodoTiendas" mode="store">
    <Stores>
      <tienda_nombre>
        <xsl:value-of select="tienda_code"/>
      </tienda_nombre>
      <cantidad>
        <xsl:value-of select="cantidad_disponible"/>
      </cantidad>
    </Stores>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola estimados buenos días, pude lograr obtener la salida que quería, en caso tengan un problema similar, espero que esto los pueda ayudar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="keyItemCode" match="//Tiendas/NodoTiendas" use="concat(generate-id(..),item_code,tienda_code)" /> 
<xsl:key name="keyItem" match="//NodoTiendas" use="item_code" /> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Tiendas>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="/Tiendas/NodoTiendas[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyItem',item_code))]">
            <xsl:variable name="vTiendaCode" select="tienda_code"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vItemCode" select="item_code"/>
            <NodoTiendas>
                <ItemCode><xsl:value-of select="$vItemCode" /></ItemCode>

                <xsl:for-each select="/Tiendas/NodoTiendas[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyItemCode',concat(generate-id(..),item_code,tienda_code)))]">
                <xsl:variable name="vkeyGroup" select="key('keyItemCode',concat(generate-id(..),item_code,tienda_code))"/>
                     <xsl:if test="$vItemCode = $vkeyGroup/item_code">
                        <Stores>
                            <tiendaNombre>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$vkeyGroup/tienda_code" />
                            </tiendaNombre>
                            <cantidad>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$vkeyGroup/cantidad_disponible" />
                            </cantidad>
                        </Stores>
                   </xsl:if> 
                </xsl:for-each>

            </NodoTiendas>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Tiendas>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```